# Here Maps - Prevent map from showing grey area outside of map

Tags: javascript, here-api, heremaps

So, I can't find anywhere on the Here Maps API an option to prevent the map from showing the grey area that is rendered outside of the map.

[You can visualize the grey area by dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05VYd.png), [or by zooming out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4JTA.png).

This makes the map feels kinda amateur, to say the least.

So far I've looked on the entire documentation, but couldn't find anything, also I've tried to block it by using the restrict panning behavior `map.getViewModel().addEventListener('sync', ...`, but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: I am not sure if the HERE Maps for JavaScript API supports this, but you could try to add a raster tile layer source that loads below the map tiles. And this custom tile layer source could be configured so that it shows something else on an index layer below the standard map tiles.

Comment: Oh but it no beneath a tile, it's on de edges of the map when it wrapping, it just allow the use too see past the -90º to 90º and -180º to 180º boundaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grey area seen during fast zoom out is because it takes time to access the tile image over internet connection from server.
However, the grey image seen at the maximum zoom-out can managed by restricting the map view at specific rectangular geographic area defined by the geographic coordinates of its top-left and bottom-right corners.

Method Name:

```
new H.geo.Rect (top, left, bottom, right)
```

API Reference:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.26.0/api_reference/H.geo.Rect.html

Code Snippet:

```js
function restrictMap(map){

  var bounds = new H.geo.Rect(37.829, -122.426, 37.824, -122.42);
  var prevGoodBounds;

  map.getViewModel().addEventListener('sync', function(e) {
            var curZoom = e.newValue.zoom,
                newZoom = false,
                mapViewBounds = map.getViewModel().getLookAtData().bounds.getBoundingBox(),
                topMap = mapViewBounds.getTop(),
                bottomMap = mapViewBounds.getBottom();
        //console.log("prevGoodBounds:", prevGoodBounds);
                
            
            //if(curZoom > this.opt.maxZoom || curZoom < this.opt.minZoom){
                //console.log("sync curZoom > this.opt.maxZoom || curZoom < this.opt.minZoom", this.opt);
                //if(curZoom > this.opt.maxZoom) newZoom = this.opt.maxZoom;
                //if(curZoom < this.opt.minZoom) newZoom = this.opt.minZoom;

                //var runLater = function(newZoom){
                    //map.setZoom(newZoom);
                //};
                //runLater.delay(50, this, newZoom);
            //}
            
            
            if(topMap > 85 || bottomMap < -85) {
                //console.log("sync topMap > 83 || bottomMap < -83", topMap, bottomMap, this.opt);
                
                if(prevGoodBounds){
                    //var runLater = function(){
                        map.setZoom(prevGoodBounds.zoom);
                        map.setCenter(prevGoodBounds.center);
                    //};
                    //runLater.delay(0, this);
                }
            }
            
            if(topMap <= 85 && bottomMap >= -85) {
                prevGoodBounds = {center: map.getCenter(), zoom: map.getZoom()};
            }
        });

  //Debug code to visualize where your restriction is
  /*map.addObject(new H.map.Rect(bounds, {
    style: {
        fillColor: 'rgba(55, 85, 170, 0.1)',
        strokeColor: 'rgba(55, 85, 170, 0.6)',
        lineWidth: 8
      }
    }
  ));*/
}
```

Complete Example: https://jsfiddle.net/raj0665/8oLyfent/

Comment: Just to be clear, the grey area during fast zoom out or pan are fine, they're tilesets loading, but this sample you've provided is just what I was talking about, thanks :)